# Align embed video to the center of the page

Tags: html, css, frontend

How could I put the video at the center of the page?
Here is my html

```
<article data-history-node-id="6" role="article" about="/ru/node/6" class="node ml-2 mr-2 node--type-video node--promoted node--view-mode-teaser clearfix">
    <header>
        <h2 class="node__title text-center">
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark">
               <span class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden">Test</span>
            </a>
        </h2>
    </header>
    <div class="node__content clearfix">
        <div class="field field--name-field-youtube-video field--type-video-embed-field field--label-hidden justify-content-center align-content-center field__item">
        <div class="video-embed-field-provider-youtube col-auto">
            <iframe width="340" height="220" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/73zdOIulcnQ?autoplay=1&amp;start=0&amp;rel=0">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

and some CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.col-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: none;
}
.justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

`justify-content-center` doesn't really help.

Some more html and css are here:
https://codepen.io/lomachx/pen/GRJYNdv

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class **justify-content-center** in the below div.it will work.

You have to identify the correct container for that.

```
<div class="view-content row justify-content-center">...</div>
```

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.col-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: none;
}
.content {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #adb5bd;
}
.node--view-mode-teaser {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d7d9;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
.field--type-video-embed-field {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 500px;
}
.justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left clearfix">
    <main class="main-content col" id="content" role="main">
     <section class="section">
   <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>
   <div data-drupal-messages-fallback class="hidden"></div>
   <div id="block-gp-page-title" class="block block-core block-page-title-block">
    <div class="content">
     <h2 class="title text-center mt-4 mb-4">Video</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="block-gp-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block">
    <div class="content">
     <div class="views-element-container col-auto">
      <div class="view view-video view-id-video view-display-id-page_1 js-view-dom-id-4e20251f96bb713d45e0e3a547b7a6680520977f1b90eae104916b0a1f3e4163">
       <div class="view-content row justify-content-center">
        <div class="views-row">
         <article data-history-node-id="6" role="article" about="/ru/node/6" class="node ml-2 mr-2 node--type-video node--promoted node--view-mode-teaser clearfix">
          <header>
           <h2 class="node__title text-center">
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark">
             <span class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden">Test</span>
            </a>
           </h2>
          </header>
          <div class="node__content clearfix">
           <div class="field field--name-field-youtube-video field--type-video-embed-field field--label-hidden justify-content-center align-content-center field__item mx-auto">
            <div class="video-embed-field-provider-youtube col-auto mx-auto">
             <iframe width="340" height="220" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </article>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
     </section>
    </main>
</div>
```